# Getting data from a file and printing it out every time a new line starts

Tags: c, arrays, string, file

Im Completely new to programming but need to get a program running as part of my training. The programs ultimate goal is to read files from a database and then send them to the client who is asking for it.

Currently im just learning how to read strings from a file and write it to a different file. But my problem is that I want to print data out every time i hit a new line.

The data in the file im using is in the following format:
`<DESCRIPTION>data,<DESCRIPTION>data,<DESCRIPTION>data` etc.
The data is both int and chars.

Since the data is seperated with a "," i was thinking of first puting all `"<DESCRIPTION>data"` into substrings with the strtok function i managed to find while googling, after that i would scan only for the "DESCRIPTION" part and then put the desired data into an array that I then would print out when reaching the end of the array (end of the line) and then move on to the next line until End of file.

What functions can I use to fix this? Or how do I set up a loop that wont take forever by scanning all chars in the line everytime it wants data? If what im saying and what im doing is 2 different things I again apologize for being a total beginner at programming. I have been prgramming for a week now and this is all I could produce

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void get9202() {
  char
  const * str;
  const char s = ",";
  char * token;

  /*open database file*/
  FILE * fp = fopen("datafile.dat", "r");

  /*create array with all lines of data
  I would like it to be able to handle unknown amounts of data.
  current file is ~177000 lines of data.*/
  int i = 0;
  char line[i];

  /*checking until end of file*/
  while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {
    /*This part has to be included in the loop somehow but put in here 
    so that you might get a picture of what im trying to do.*/

    while ( * str) {
      if (!isspace( * str++))
        i++;
      else break;
      /*not entirely sure how to exit this subloop 
                         to print out the data and go to new line*/
    }

    /*trying to segment the string into an array of substrings 
    but dont know when to introduce x*/
    token[x] = strtok(str, s);

    while (token[x] != NULL) {
      printf("%s\n,", token);
    }

  }

  return result;
  /* dont know how to return the file to main*/
  flclose("datafile.dat");
}
```

If the data looks like this:

```
<SYMBOL>9202.T,<SYMSTAT>2,<MSGSTAT>0,<TIME>20:50:40.905246,<SYS_DT>2018/07/19,<SYS_TIM>20:50:40.503,<SYS_TIMU>20:50:40.503236
<SYMBOL>9202.T,<SYMSTAT>2,<MSGSTAT>0,<TIME>20:51:40.000235,<SYS_DT>2018/07/19,<SYS_TIM>20:51:39.598,<SYS_TIMU>20:51:39.598597
```

the expected file could look like

```
9202.T,2,0,20:50:40.905246
9202.T,2,0,20:51:40.000235
```

as the wanted pieces are being selected some will fall away.

Comment: `int i=0;
char line[i];` ? It will become `char line[0]`.

Comment: `int i=0; char line[i];` is the same as `char line[0];`. There's no room for anything.

Comment: So just doing int i; would work?

Comment: @Cordisater Nope, `i` will have indeterminate value. What is the maximum length of line?

Comment: Can i set the buffer to lets say 3000 and it wouldnt read in \n etc? Currently the longest line is 2448 chars long.

Comment: I tried to fix the formatting so your input and output examples make sense.

Comment: If every line has the same shape, this looks like a job for `fscanf`.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thank you! About the fscanf I will look into it a bit more

Comment: @Cordisater See the example below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Few problems:**

1. *Will declare zero length array.*

   ```
   int i=0;
   char line[i];
   ```
2. *`fclose` is never executed because of `return` also `fclose` needs `FILE *` as argument.*

   ```
   return result; 
   /* dont know how to return the file to main*/
   flclose("datafile.dat");
   ```

**Suggestions:**

> trying to segment the string into an array of substrings  but dont
>   know when to introduce x

*Use `fgets` with `fscanf` to parse your line since all the lines are identical.*

> dont know how to return the file to main

*Define a `structure` with needed fields and return it to `main`.*

---

**Example:**

```
typedef struct {

  char symbol[50];
  char symstat;
  char msgstat;
  char time[50];
}data;

data *get9202(int *numData) {

  int memAllocated = 10;
  data *mData = malloc(sizeof(*mData) * memAllocated);

  FILE *fp = fopen("datafile.dat", "r");

  char buf[3000];
  int i = 0;

  while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp) != NULL) {

    if (i == memAllocated) {
      memAllocated *= 2;

      void *temp = realloc(mData, sizeof( *mData) * memAllocated);
      if (temp != NULL) mData = temp;
      else break; //error
    }

    if (sscanf(buf, "<SYMBOL>%[^,],<SYMSTAT>%c,<MSGSTAT>%c,<TIME>%[^,]",
        mData[i].symbol, &mData[i].symstat, &mData[i].msgstat, mData[i].time) == 4) {
      i++;
    } else {
      printf("error\n"); //error
    }
  }
  fclose(fp);

  *numData = i;
  return mData;
}

int main() {
  int len = 0;
  data *mData = get9202( &len);

  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    printf("%s,%c,%c,%s\n", mData[i].symbol, mData[i].symstat, mData[i].msgstat,
      mData[i].time);

  if (mData) free(mData);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try edit a bit more for my purpose but i think i got the basic thinking down now.